# Extjs6 treegrid column scrollable does not work

Tags: extjs

I'm using ExtJs6,but when I using the TreeGrid I want the scroll bar in the **column**
when I expand more node on the tree ,I don't want the column width change.
So the value can't display complete,
I saw the docs

> scrollable : Boolean / String / Object 
>   Configuration options to make this Component scrollable. Acceptable values are:
>   true to enable auto scrolling.
>   false (or null) to disable scrolling - this is the default.
>   x or horizontal to enable horizontal scrolling only
>   y or vertical to enable vertical scrolling only
>   Also accepts a configuration object for a Ext.scroll.Scroller if if advanced configuration is needed.
>   The getter for this config returns the Ext.scroll.Scroller instance. You can use the Scroller API to read or manipulate the scroll position:

but I write the code like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'treecolumn', //this is so we know which column will show the tree
    text: 'operation',
    sortable: true,
    width: 200,
    border: 5,
    scrollable: true,
    dataIndex: 'operation',
    menuDisabled: true,
    autoSizeColumn: true
}
```

it was not work..

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1fad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid column body cannot have a scrollbar. `gridcolumn` derives from component, but all the inherited configs and properties are configuring the column header.

The way the `gridpanel` is rendered underneath (the way the HTML is generated) rules out any simple and performant way of adding horizontal scrolling to a single column.

Depending on your use case, you can add your `treecolumn` as a locked column.

In the `lockedGridConfig` you can then provide a fixed width for the locked part of the grid, and `scrollable:true`. This is the only way I see to have that column scroll horizontally independently from the rest of the grid.

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1faf